# Submit Unity/Prime31 App for Permission Review - Can't create Simulator Build

Tags: facebook, permissions, unity-game-engine, review, prime31

We are in the process of creating a word game for iOS based on Unity3D. The game uses Prime31 Plugins for Social networking. The issue is that we are not able to generate a Simulator build, which is required for Facebook's Permissions review (our App requires publish_action permission, for which review is mandatory). We did some R&D and found out a solution as below.

http://support.prime31.com/13690/how-to-create-a-package-for-facebook-review?show=13690

We are not so sure if we want to try the steps mentioned above, so we hoped you could help us out.

Comment: Up-voting because we've hit the same issue.

Comment: @99Games Online  did you find solution?